# Symfony app deployment with docker

Tags: symfony, docker, deployment, web-deployment, docker-compose

I come here because I develop an app with Symfony3. And I've some questions about the deployment of the app.
Actually I use docker-compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
        build: ./docker/nginx/
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        volumes:
            - .:/home/docker:ro
            - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
            - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
        networks:
            - default

    php:
        build: ./docker/php/
        volumes:
            - .:/home/docker:rw
            - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini:ro
        working_dir: /home/docker
        networks:
            - default
        dns_search:
            - php

    db:
        image: mariadb:latest
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=collectionManager
            - MYSQL_USER=collectionManager
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=collectionManager
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=collectionManager
        volumes:
            - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
        dns_search:
            - db

    search:
        build: ./docker/search/
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300
        volumes:
            - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        networks:
            - default
        dns_search:
            - search

volumes:
    mariadb_data:
        driver: local
    elasticsearch_data:
        driver: local

networks:
    default:
```

nginx is clear, engine is PHP-FPM with some extensions and composer, db is MariaDB, and search ElasticSearch with some plugins.

Before I don't use Docker and to deploy I used Megallanes or Deployer, when I want to deploy  webapp.

With Docker I can use the docker-compose file and recreate images and container on the server, I also can save my containers in images and in tar archive and load it on the server. It's okay for nginx, and php-fpm, but what about elasticsearch and the db ? Because I need to keep data in for future update of the code. Then when I deploy the code I need to execute a Doctrine Migration and maybe some commands, and Deployer do it perfectly with some other interresting things. And how I deploy the code with Docker ? Can we use both ? Deployer for code and Docker for services ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all , Please try using user-defined networks, they have additional features vs legacy linking like Embedded DNS. Meaning you can call other containers on the same network with their names in your applications. Containers on a User defined network are isolate from containers on another User defined network.

To create a user defined network:

```
docker network create --driver bridge <networkname>
```

Dockerfile to use user defined network example:

```
search:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: ./docker/search/
    ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"
    networks:
        - <networkname>
```

Second: I noticed you didnt use data volumes for you DB and ElasticSearch.
You need to mount volumes at certain points to keep your persistant data.

Third: When you export your containers it wont contain mounted volumes. You need to back up volume data and migrate it manually.

To backup volume data:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from db -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

The above command will create a container, mounts volumes from DB container and mounts current directory in container as `/backup` , uses `ubuntu image` and `tar` command to create a backup of `/dbdata` in container (consider changing this to your dbdirectory) in the `/backup` that is mounted from your docker hosts). after the operation completes the transient container will be removed (ubuntu container we used for creating the backup with `--rm` switch).

To restore:

You copy the `tar` archive to the remote location and create your container with empty mounted volume. then extract the tar archive in that volume using the following command.

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from dbstore2 -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd /dbdata && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar --strip 1"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I've do a volume mount for ElasticSearch and Mariadb. But I don't understand the first point, user defined networks ?

Comment: Edited the answer with more info.

Comment: I've edit my code and use networks, and volumes. But I don't really know what to do with my source code :/

Comment: Cool, Now you should mount your source code to nginx `document root`. Look at your `nginx config`. find the `document root`, then mount your source code directory to nginx container like what you did with `nginx.conf` file.

Comment: Yes I do it in development, the when I edit my code it directly used. But I search a method to deploy it in production. (just test, not really production yest). But I read somewhere the source code of the project may be in a container, some says the opposite.

Comment: You create a folder put your docker compose and folders that need to be mounted in it, zip it and ship it. then on target (production environment) unzip, and bring it up with docker compose file. Please note that host path for mounted folders/files is relative so it should work anywhere.

Comment: Is it really answering the question ? I think It was more about deploying an application with Docker. For example building Docker images, pulling them from the production and deploy them with zero downtime.

Comment: Not really, bu I search again. For the moment I just use a different docker-compose on server, and I create a symfony_volume in which I put the code with a script (I pull from github, and execute composer, bin/console from the php container). But I'm not sure that's the better way to do it... And I can't use deployment tools that already exist because there is a problem with the symlink... For the schema: current (symlink on the last release), releases, share. All symlinks are created directly on the server, but the container can't follow them...  I've no idea how to do with only one server.